# How to handle online captchas in WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Like: 1+ 7 =

A website has a text box and this text box will accept the input of sum of two numbers. How we capture these two number like 1 and 7. And any number can be come at this location.

Please help me out.

Comment: Catpchas are intended to defeat automated programs exactly like Selenium, so getting around this will be difficult by design. Typically you would want to have a way to configure your (assuming your're testing your site and not writing a bot) website to disable the captcha for your test (so you can test the real functionality).  Alternatively, you can target those two numbers like you would target anything else in Selenium.  What have you tried?

Comment: See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12416/automation-and-bypassing-google-no-captcha-recaptcha/

Answer (score 1):

```java
String capchavalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText();
int firstinteger= Integer.parseInt(capchavalue.substring(0, 2));
int secondinteger= Integer.parseInt(capchavalue.substring(5, 6));
int calc= firstinteger+secondinteger;
String final_value= String.valueOf(calc);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys(final_value);
```

Comment: Some explanation along with the code would have been of use.

Comment: Hi anuj, and welcome to Stack Overflow! your code might be correct, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it, because if "machine" can solve it, CAPTCHA (Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart) isn't doing it's job.

What you can do, is to use API of external services such as http://www.deathbycaptcha.com. They can solve the CAPTCHA "for you" and the response time is about 15 seconds.

Implementation example:

```
import com.DeathByCaptcha.AccessDeniedException;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.Captcha;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.Client;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.SocketClient;
import com.DeathByCaptcha.HttpClient;

/* Put your DeathByCaptcha account username and password here.
   Use HttpClient for HTTP API. */
Client client = (Client)new SocketClient(username, password);
try {
    double balance = client.getBalance();

    /* Put your CAPTCHA file name, or file object, or arbitrary input stream,
       or an array of bytes, and optional solving timeout (in seconds) here: */
    Captcha captcha = client.decode(captchaFileName, timeout);
    if (null != captcha) {
        /* The CAPTCHA was solved; captcha.id property holds its numeric ID,
           and captcha.text holds its text. */
        System.out.println("CAPTCHA " + captcha.id + " solved: " + captcha.text);

        if (/* check if the CAPTCHA was incorrectly solved */) {
            client.report(captcha);
        }
    }
} catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
    /* Access to DBC API denied, check your credentials and/or balance */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't automate captacha but can Handle those.
scenario:
1. enter username
2. enter captcha in console manually 
3. enter password

```
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String captcha;   
            System.out.println("Please Enter the CAPTCHA Code:: ");
            captcha = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Entered  CAPTCHA Code is:: "+captcha);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Automation is only possible of you get support from the dev team to have a way to get around the captcha. This can be done by fixed long tokens instead, disabling of captchas on dev environments, providing static captchas for the purpose of testing and the like.

You cannot automate a regular captcha without any problems, trouble or time problems. Captchas are made to prevent automation.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a manual solution, like this:

```
input_captcha = input("Entered CAPTCHA Code is: ")
browser.find_element_by_id("j_captcha").send_keys(input_captcha)
```

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA - Completely Automated Public Turing Test to tell Computers and Humans Apart. 
If you automate it you are killing the sole purpose of creating Captcha on your website. 
Request your devs to disable it on your QA environment and continue with your tests or use predefined cookies (hardcoded CAPTCHA).

Answer (score -1):

```java
String capchavalue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("#")).getText().trim();
String removespace = capchavalue.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
String[] parts = removespace.split("\\+");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String[] parts1 = part2.split("\\=");
String part11 = parts1[0];
int summation = Integer.parseInt(part1) + Integer.parseInt(part11);
String final_value = String.valueOf(summation);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("#")).sendKeys(final_value);
```

Comment: @anuj answers valid but only for perfect two single digits. Not for two digits. eg 12+13 , 12+1 , 1+24

Comment: Also consider adding any comment where you explain your code.